# Write Header Record to CSV File

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using CSVHelper to write a DataReader result to a csv file and everything works great except that I need my header names to be manually entered instead of just pulling the column name from the datareader.

**So currently I use the following to get my data and place a header:** It comes right from the documentation of CSVHelper: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#misc-faq

```
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (!hasHeaderBeenWritten)
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        csv.WriteField(rdr.GetName(i));
                    }
                    csv.NextRecord();
                    hasHeaderBeenWritten = true;

                    foreach (var item in dataList)
                    {
                        csv.WriteRecord(item);
                    }
                }
                for (var i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(rdr[i]);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
```

I'm looking basically to add a manual name to the 3 columns that my class is allow it to return vs the rdr.GetName(i) method that is being used above.

Does anyone have any solutions? I've tried doing a csv.WriteField("namehere"[i]); which obviously didn't work and instead spanned each letter out across the three columns and then stopped.

Comment: Create an array containing your manual column names in the matching index position as your `rdr` then when outputting the column headers read the column name from this array, eg. `csv.WriteField(myColumnHeaders[i]);`

Comment: I haven't tried this but what about writing that header to the file before CSVHelper get's to it? OR you can just write your values to a file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: "**HOW DO I PROPERLY ADD A CUSTOM HEADER IN CSVHELPER?**"

Simply create an string array with the column names you wish and pass them in using `csv.WriteField(*ARRAYHERE*)[i];` and for each column a they will be added in order they appear in the array.

**Create they array:**

```
string[] arrayHeader = new string[] { "Header1", "Header2", "Header3" };
```

**Pass each column name in:**

```
                    for (var i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        //csv.WriteField(rdr.GetName(i));
                        csv.WriteField(arrayHeader[i]);
                    }
```

Comment: glad you figured it out. FYI, `csv.WriteField("namehere"[i]); ` is writing a single character into each field because a string is an array of characters, so using `<string>[i]` pulls the character at location `i`.

Comment: Thank you for that understanding!